# php strtotime displaying month as day

Tags: php

I am constructing a diary that has weekly views which I thought I had cracked because the dates seemed to appears as correct.  It wasn't until my MySQL queries kept returning what seemed like random results that I realized the the month is actually being seen as the day instead.

```
$week_number = date("W");
$year = date("Y");

for ($day=0; $day<=6; $day++) {
    $daily_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($year."W".$week_number.$day))."\n";
    $StartDate = date('d', strtotime($daily_date));
}

echo $starteDate;
```

`$startDate` returns the number of the month rather than the day and sure enough `date('m', strtotime($daily_date))` returns the day rather than the month.

I can't understand where I have made this silly mistake so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the Americanisation of dates - strtotime will read the date as m/d/Y rather than d/m/Y.

The [ISO for dates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is Y-m-d and for ease I would use this format when doing any kind of date manipulation.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I admit that it took me a while to realise that I needed to use hyphens instead of forward slashes but when I did it worked.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

That code is horrible. You're converting dates to strings multiple times. There is absolutely NO reason to take your `$year . w. $week_number.etc...` value, convert it to a string, then convert that string back to a date just to extract the day value.

As well, d/m/Y is a horrible format to use for date transport, because... riddle me this, what is 01/02/03. Is that 3rd Feb 2001? 1 Mar 2002? If you can't figure it out, how can you expect strtotime to be better at it? it's fairly smart, but it's not omnicient, and it's DEFINITELY not infallible. A 4digit year does make it a bit easier, but you can still end up with `d/m` v.s. `m/d` confusion.

Why not simply

```
$StartDate = date('d', strtotime($year."W".$week_number.$day));
```

or better yet, use the [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) class and select an appropriate [DateInterval](http://php.net/dateinterval)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I originally tried your suggestion but it didn't work so I just tried passing the a whole variable instead because the variable seemed to dispaly correctly.  It seems that the problem was that I used d/m/y instead of d-m-y.  I didn't know that one was American time format and the other was european